# Android DialogFragment: How to preserve view in multiple show() invocation?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment using a custom layout with a quite complex View hierarchy. The code for the dialog fragment is more or less similar to the following.

```
public class CardDetailDialog extends DialogFragment { 

    public CardDetailDialog() { 
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Light);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_detail_dialog, container, false);
        /* Modify some view objects ... */
        return view;
    }
}
```

Whenever I invoked the `show()` method for this dialog fragment, I noticed that `onCreateView` is always called and layout inflation process is repeated. In my app, user might want to show the dialog multiple times during a session and I thought this is inefficient. Is there any way to keep the view / dialog instance across multiple `show()` invocation? Is it possible to do this using DialogFragment, or do I have to deal directly with `Dialog` class?

Answer (score 1):

Using a boolean flag seems to do the trick (See the KEY CHANGEs). I override onCreateDialog, but employing the same strategy in onCreateView should work as well (keep a reference to your view you create)

I'm still getting some issues related to Orientation changes, but it may be related to [a different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657490/how-to-properly-retain-a-dialogfragment-through-rotation)

```
public class LogFragment extends DialogFragment{

private boolean isCreated;  //KEY CHANGE
private Dialog mDialog;     //KEY CHANGE -- to hold onto dialog instance across show()s

public LogFragment() {
    setRetainInstance(true); // This keeps the fields across activity lifecycle
    isCreated = false;       // KEY CHANGE - we create the dialog/view the 1st time
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle inState) {
    if (isCreated) return mDialog;  // KEY CHANGE - don't recreate, just send it back
    View v = View.inflate(getActivity(),R.layout.log_layout,null);
    mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            ...
            .create();
    isCreated = true;  // KEY CHANGE Set the FLAG
    return mDialog;
}
```